# What's the difference between these two statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between these two snippets apart from just pure preference in which you use? As I've seen both used a lot and am not sure how/why they differ other than just preference in terms of readability.

```
object.foo = function () {

    //code

}

foo : function () {

    //code

}
```

Comment: I take it the 2nd one should be wrapped with `object = {}`?  If so, then they literally are exactly the same

Comment: On it's own the 2nd statement isn't valid syntax. Like @Archer has said this would be the same as the first if it's wrapped in `object = {}`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! I completely missed the objects wrapping around this. Although, is saying foo = function() {} the same as foo : function () {} when you're assigning to properties within an object?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same thing.  You would normally use the 2nd method when declaring an object, and the 1st when extending it later (if you needed to).

Comment: Ah awesome! So = and : is just preference, good to know.

Comment: No - they're completely different syntax.  See my answer below for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing in the example you've given, but there are some slight differences which explain why there are seemingly 2 ways to do the same thing.

Take this example...

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

You can then extend that object like this...

```
obj.bar = function() {
    // do something different
};
```

But if you did this...

```
obj = {
    bar: function() {
        // do something different
    }
};
```

... you would lose the function `foo`.  So one method is for explicitly declaring an object, complete with properties and functions, and the other method can be used for extending an existing object.

Just to be perfectly clear, this is incorrect syntax...

```
var obj = {
    foo = function() {    // it should be foo: function() {}
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: In your third example, can you replace bar: function() {} with bar = function() {} and it still be valid? That's what I was asking before, sorry if I didn't make that clear EDIT: You answered my question with your edit, thanks!

Comment: I just added a bit at the end to cover the `:` and `= ` thing.  This is down to object declaration syntax.  Outside the curly braces it's `=`, but inside it's `:`

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
object = {
    foo : function () {
        // code
    }
}
```

is the complete way to write the second statement, meaning you define the function in the initialization of the object.

This code:

```
object.foo = function () {
    //code
}
```

can be used both as a shorthand, and if you want to declare the function dynamically *after* the declaration of the object.